# Deleting All inbox messages at once

Tags: facebook, message

Is there any option to delete all the messages at once?
Dear Dev, please make an option in the inbox to mark or remove all the messages at once.It is very hard to delete messages one by one in a single time. I hope in the next update,you can make a change in this matter. Thanks a lot for this. I hope there will be a respond A.S.A.P

Comment: you do know you can delete a conversation without deleteing messages one by one, right? also, this is no place to suggest things to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you meant facebook messages, basing on your tag.

And I think, this is the wrong website to be posting this.

But anyways, there isn't any. AFAIK. Since facebook messages are conversations, saved. You'd have to delete all conversations.

If you do google you can search for guides to do it with one click,
using 3rd party plugins, with the chrome browser specifically. But personally, I'm not a fan of 3rd party plugins that would give access to my personal info.